# Произношение фамилии Мюнхгаузен

Tags: орфоэпия, ономастика

Её следует произносить аналогично слову *бухгалтер* — с фрикативным [γ], со взрывным [г] или вовсе без такового — ***хга*** = *[ха]*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Фамилию Мюнхгаузен следует произносить так: [м' у н **х á** у **з э** н]. В этом слове нет фрикативного или взрывного г, *хга* произносится как [ха], а *зен* как [зэн].

Источник: «Словарь собственных имен русского языка» Ф. Л. Агеенко.